classic menu indicator on ubuntu24.04
I like openbox with Tint2 best.
I've installed classicmenu-indicator on Lubuntu24.04.
But it does not appear when I log in to openbox.
And when I was going to configure "tint2 settings" , it crushed.
It's still working on 22.04 as ever.
